# Xcode 8 (swift 3) What its an entity's type?

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios10

What is the correct type for an Entity?

For example, when saving a value to an attribute of an entity, what type declaration should replace the three question marks below?

```
func setSample() {
    let saveSample: <type???> = SampleEntity(context: context)
    saveSample.sampleAttribute = "Save a new string."
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
         print("Error with save: \(error)")
    }
}
```

FWIW: NSEntityDescription returns the errors:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'SampleEntity' to specified type 'NSEntityDescription'
Value of type 'NSEntityDescription' has no member 'sampleAttribute'
```

Context I'd like make the entity into a variable to do something like this:

```
func setSample() {
    var saveSample: ??? 
    if (criteria) { saveSample = Entity1(context: context) }
    if (criteria) { saveSample = Entity2(context: context) }
    if (criteria) { saveSample = Entity3(context: context) }
    saveSample.sampleAttribute1 = "Foo"
    saveSample.sampleAttribute2 = "Bar"
    saveSample.sampleAttributeNth = "Etc"
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
         print("Error with save: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more context about exactly what you're trying to achieve, and what the declarations of `Entity1` and `Entity2` are.

Comment: @ Alexander Momchliov, `Entity1`, `Entity2`, `Entity3` are the Entity names as listed in CoreData.xcdatamodeld.

Answer (score 0):

Use `??? = SampleEntity` or remove the `???` part completely:

```
let saveSample = SampleEntity(context: context)
let saveSample: SampleEntity = SampleEntity(context: context)
let saveSample: SampleEntity
```

Comment: That doesn't work in the latter approach, in which he's forward declaring a variable to be filled in later with one of multiple options, based on some criteria.